# DB Select Query with Related Links to related pages

Tags: 7, database

I am displaying data from database with list format, as shown here:

```
<?php  
        $dbresult = db_query("SELECT country_name FROM {countries} order by country_name ASC");
        $theanswer[] = $row->country_name;
        ?>
        <ul>
        <li><a class="normal-list list-group-item active" href="#">Countries</a></li>
        <li><form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filter" value="" placeholder="Search By Country" />
                <span id="filter-count"></span>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="commentlist">
            <?php foreach($dbresult as $row){ ?><li></li>
            <li><a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i><?php echo $row->country_name; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            </ul>
```

I want to get the link to every list related link.

In Drupal 7 can we connect basic pages which we are creates dynamically can we hava a chance to related links, or any other way?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! So far, you stated facts without asking any explicit question. Where are you stuck at? What exactly aren't you able to understand?